# Select whole period of time in a group when at least one value in the column is true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a select statement that would enable me to view the whole period of time if the constraint is true at least once. Attached is a snippet of the table that I am working with. Featured are aluminium electrolysis cells called A042 and A043 (mytable.pot), date_time (mytable.dags), the constraint, boolean, vanadium concentration (mytable.V_low) and the row number (mytable.Rn). [My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXnSo.png) As you see the constraint is true only for 3 days of the 9 day period featured for A042, but I want the query to return all dates before and after the constraint is 1. In other words, if it is 1 at least once, it should return the whole 9 day period for the given pot.

The reason is that there are many pots to inspect and this value is usually 0. Therefore when an anomaly is detected I need a report on the whole period for the given pot. In the example shown here it should only return the 9 day period for pot A042 since the constraint is 0 for all the A043 days.

How can I create another column (mytable.Low_period) that would be 1 for all the days of pot A042 but 0 for all A043, so that I could then easily end the statement with (where mytable.Low_period = 1) ? Other suggestions are also welcome.

I do not have admin access to create procedures and/or alter tables.

Thanks in advance

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXnSo.png)

Comment: If you cannot create/alter tables, then you cannot create another column.  Perhaps you are asking for help with a select query.  I suggest that you provide an example of what you have tried (your query) so far, and what does not work about it.  Also, if you could supply the desired results, that would be helpful.  Finally, providing the data examples as inline text is better than an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(v_low) over (partition by pot) as max_v_low
      from t
     ) t
where max_v_low > 0;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, exactly what I wanted.